# Detecting The Used Mouse-Deviced On Mac

Tags: swift, macos, mouseevent, mouse

How can I determine, which input device caused a pointer movement. This of only given the condition, that at least two mice are connected to the mac.
This is a rather specific problem and I did not found any solution googling it jet so any idea or starting point would be a huge help.

The 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854185/multiple-mice-on-os-x) as suggested by Willeke seems to go into the right direction. However, the mentioned link is broken and the answer is over 11 years old.

Does anybody know more about this topic that could be helpful?
Anything to start with would be a huge help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple mice on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854185/multiple-mice-on-os-x)

Comment: Thx, the 2nd part looks promising. However, It's over 11 yeras old and the linked sample code is no longer available. Hence I started a new Question for a state-of-the-art aproach.